# Import date from csv file as DATE format in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, csv, date, import, converters

I have a csv file that i want to create a database from. Now everything works fine except for the date that is now stored in a VARCHAR column.

Is it possible to make it so that the date get stored in a DATE column when i import it from my phpMyAdmin? The csv looks like this:

```
Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR,HTHG,HTAG,HTR
29-09-2017,Excelsior,Vitesse,0,3,A,0,1,A
30-09-2017,Heracles,Feyenoord,2,4,A,0,3,A
30-09-2017,Willem II,Den Haag,1,2,A,0,1,A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `LOAD DATA` and inline a call to `STR_TO_DATE` to convert your string dates on the fly:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'yourfile.csv'
INTO TABLE yourTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(@Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTHG, FTAG, FTR, HTHG, HTAG, HTR)
SET Date = STR_TO_DATE(@Date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

By the way, you are absolutely making the right design decision by storing your date information as actual dates, and not just as text.  Storing dates as text opens the door for problems later on when you actually go to use your database table.

Comment: Hi tim, no errors but the Date column stays empty (all NULL). I just changed the path and tablename in your code, is there something i’m missing?

Comment: So you're saying that the entire table loads using my answer, except the date column is null everywhere?  Or, are you saying that nothing loads at all?  I don't see any logical problems with my code.  If your date strings are all what you showed, then I think it should be working.

Comment: Yeah, not sure what i did different but tried it again just now and it works...thanks Tim!

Comment: The date field may be empty if there is a problem with the format in the CSV file, or the format inside STR_TO_DATE. I had to convert my CSV from "01-Jan-2023" to "2023-Jan-01" for it to work properly.